# Firebase Offline Login Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Please I'm working on a project on Android that requires me use full offline capabilities with Firebase and I'm stuck with the how to login offline.

I have tried the data storing section with firestore fully working but don't know how to for login.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly logging in (by calling on of the `signIn` APIs) requires that you have an active internet connection.

Restoring an existing sign-in (by reading the current user or [listening for authentication state](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68104924/listen-for-authentication-state-in-android) will work even when there's no internet connection.